# Is there an ADO.Net provider for SQLite version 3.7+?

Tags: ado.net, sqlite, dataprovider

The ADO.Net provider available at http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/ is version 1.0.66.0 Apr 18, 2010, for SQLite 3.6.23.1.

I see there is a commercial provider available at [devart](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/overview.html).

Is there an open source provider available that supports SQLite 3.7+, preferably the latest version 3.7.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We provide a free [Standard Edition](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/editions.html) as well. Maybe it suits your needs?

Comment: I will check it out. Can the free standard edition be deployed royalty free with a commercial application?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Our product is licensed for developers (not for a workstation or a server).

Comment: This performs well so far and does answer my question of looking for an ADO.Net provider that supports SQLite version 3.7+. Regarding open source provider, it would appear that as of this time, it is still under development and not available.